# How to implement GLM regression from scratch?

Tags: regression, python, generalized-linear-model, statsmodels

I wrote the following code in Python. First I generate some data:

```
# generate data
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 5, 1000)
x2 = np.random.normal(20, 5, 1000)
error = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
y = np.exp(3*x1 + 6*x2) + error
X = np.stack((x1,x2)).T
```

Then I pre-allocate some variables:

```
weights = np.ones(np.shape(X)[1])
learningRate = 0.0001
numberOfIterations = 10000
```

I (try to) do maximum likelihood estimation:

```
for _ in range(0, numberOfIterations):
    # the derivative of the log likelihood for the Poisson distribution
    gradient = -1 * len(y) + 1/weights * np.sum(X, axis=0)
    
    # gradient ascent
    weights = weights + learningRate * gradient
```

Then I try verify the results with statsmodels:

```
# check outcome
check = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()

print(check.params)
print(weights)

>>>
[10.20840077 20.03072152]
[2.99 6.00]
```

As can be seen, my outcome does not match the output from `statsmodels`.

After analysis, I think I estimated the parameter of the Poisson distribution $(X \sim Poi(\mu))$, where the sample mean is the ML estimator. Indeed it can be seen (since I generated the data), that the population means are 10 and 20. Furthermore, the sample means are exactly equal to the MLE outcome. Therefore I am convinced my code is correct, but it is not what I want to calculate. I want to calculate the beta coefficients using MLE:

$$
log(\mu) = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2
\\
\mu = E(y)
\\
\mu \sim Poi(\lambda)
$$

So I want to estimate $b_1^{MLE}$ and $b_2^{MLE}$, but instead I got $\hat{\lambda}_{MLE}$.

How do I get $b_1^{MLE}$ and $b_2^{MLE}$?

Comment: Poisson uses a exponential mean function (log-link).

Comment: You need to express the gradient in terms of your coefficients.  Right now, it looks like you're gradient is in terms of $\lambda$.